# How to define CAAnimation repeat count correctly in the UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I want to create animations that includes a few UIImage objects. In the light of out investigations I  am trying to add animations to layer of UIImages.

As you can see below codes, I created animations for each UIImages and added these animations to UIImages layers. And after that I added all of these UIImages to UIView to be a subviews.

The problem is that when I added this animation class(It inherited from a UIView) to another view, it works according to determined animations properties. But the animation works only one time. Actually I want that the animation repeats until I stop it. If I want to determine repeat count for each animations, they are working asynchronous. It doesn't animate in the right order.

Finally I have to refresh all animations in related view or I have to calculate animation duration, I don't know may be I used wrong way. 
How can I solve this problem? Or may you share with me, if is there any different approach?

```
import UIKit

class ActivityIndicator: UIView {

// MARK: - Initialization

init()
{
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: 144, height: 124))
    self.setupLayers()
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setupLayers()
}

// MARK: - I added some UIImage and their animations. Begin times are nested.

private func setupLayers() {

    let repeatCount:Float = 0

    let yellowBubble = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "yellowBubble"))
    yellowBubble.frame = CGRect(x: 11.8, y: 0, width: 132.084549, height: 104.150719)
    yellowBubble.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    yellowBubble.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.center

    let blackBubble = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blackBubble"))
    blackBubble.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 17.685972, width:132.084549, height: 104.150719)
    blackBubble.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    blackBubble.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.center

    let shadowLine = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "shadowBubble"))
    shadowLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 17.685972, width: 132.084549, height: 86.464752)
    shadowLine.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    shadowLine.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.center

    let textAndSign = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logoAndSign"))
    textAndSign.frame = CGRect(x: 28.82774, y: 44.301903, width: 81, height: 44)
    textAndSign.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    textAndSign.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.center

    // Animations have a few properties that includes duration,beginTime etc.
    let allLogoAnimation = CASpringAnimation()
    allLogoAnimation.beginTime = self.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) + 2
    allLogoAnimation.duration = 3
    allLogoAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    allLogoAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    allLogoAnimation.keyPath = "transform.rotation.z"
    allLogoAnimation.toValue = 0
    allLogoAnimation.fromValue = 15
    self.layer.add(allLogoAnimation, forKey: "allLogoAnimation")

    let yellowBubbleAnimation = CASpringAnimation()
    yellowBubbleAnimation.beginTime = self.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    yellowBubbleAnimation.duration = 3
    yellowBubbleAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    yellowBubbleAnimation.speed = 1.2
    yellowBubbleAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    yellowBubbleAnimation.keyPath = "transform.translation.y"
    yellowBubbleAnimation.toValue = 0
    yellowBubbleAnimation.fromValue = -70
    yellowBubble.layer.add(yellowBubbleAnimation, forKey: "yellowBubbleAnimation")

    let blackBubbleAnimation = CASpringAnimation()
    blackBubbleAnimation.beginTime = self.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) + 0.3
    blackBubbleAnimation.duration = 3
    yellowBubbleAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    blackBubbleAnimation.speed = 1.2
    blackBubbleAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    blackBubbleAnimation.keyPath = "transform.translation.x"
    blackBubbleAnimation.toValue = 0
    blackBubbleAnimation.fromValue = -70
    blackBubble.layer.add(blackBubbleAnimation, forKey: "blackBubbleAnimation")

    let shadowLineAnimation = CASpringAnimation()
    shadowLineAnimation.beginTime = self.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) + 0.6
    shadowLineAnimation.duration = 3
    shadowLineAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    shadowLineAnimation.speed = 1.2
    shadowLineAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    shadowLineAnimation.keyPath = "transform.translation.x"
    shadowLineAnimation.toValue = 0
    shadowLineAnimation.fromValue = 70
    shadowLine.layer.add(shadowLineAnimation, forKey: "shadowLineAnimation")

    let textAndSignScaleAnimation = CASpringAnimation()
    textAndSignScaleAnimation.beginTime = self.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) + 1
    textAndSignScaleAnimation.duration = 3
    textAndSignScaleAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    textAndSignScaleAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    textAndSignScaleAnimation.keyPath = "transform.scale.xy"
    textAndSignScaleAnimation.toValue = 1
    textAndSignScaleAnimation.fromValue = 3
    textAndSign.layer.add(textAndSignScaleAnimation, forKey: "textAndSignScaleAnimation")

    let textAndSignOpacityAnimation = CASpringAnimation()
    textAndSignOpacityAnimation.beginTime = self.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) + 1
    textAndSignOpacityAnimation.duration = 3
    textAndSignOpacityAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    textAndSignOpacityAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    textAndSignOpacityAnimation.keyPath = "opacity"
    textAndSignOpacityAnimation.toValue = 1
    textAndSignOpacityAnimation.fromValue = 0
    textAndSign.layer.add(textAndSignOpacityAnimation, forKey: "textAndSignOpacityAnimation")

    self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.center
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    // I added all UIImages to ActivityIndicatorView
    self.addSubviews(yellowBubble,blackBubble,shadowLine,textAndSign)
}
}
```

After that I added a animation view to my view controller.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let activityView = ActivityIndicator()
    activityView.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.view.addSubview(activityView)

}
```

Comment: So if you pass infinity to repeat count it is not in the right order?  Which animation is the end of the base or end of the animations?

Comment: @agibson007 First animation yellowBubbleAnimation end animation is allLogoAnimation. But I tried to set infinity, it didn't work in the right order.

Comment: Probably I found the problem. When I set the animation speed all of them I solved the problem.